# How do I include a class in a link inserted in an entitiy's link area?

Tags: entities, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I want to insert a link to a ctools modal popup with a custom style (class) into the link area at the bottom of an entity (e.g. a node).  I do this using `hook_entity_view_alter`.  This is how the relevant part of my code looks like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(&$build) {
  // Set up ctools etc. to use modal omitted for brevity.
  $build['links']['popup']['#links']['mylink']['title'] = 'show popup';
  $build['links']['popup']['#links']['mylink']['href'] = 'mymodule/nojs/modals';
  $build['links']['popup']['#links']['mylink']['html'] = TRUE;
 }
```

The code shown above inserts the following link in the right place:

```
<a href="/mymodule/nojs/modals">show popup</a>
```

However, this leaves out the class required to give the modal a custom style.  This what I *really* want to have this link look like:

```
<a href="/mymodule/nojs/modals" class="ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-mymodule-style">show popup</a>
```

Question: How do I get `class="ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-mymodule-style"` included in this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the html attributes using the `attributes` key which accepts an array of attributes, and add classes using the `class` key, which also accepts an array of classes.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(&$build) {
  // Set up ctools etc. to use modal omitted for brevity.
  $build['links']['popup']['#links']['mylink'] = array(
    'title' => 'show popup',
    'href' => 'mymodule/nojs/modals',
    'html' => TRUE,
    'attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'ctools-use-modal', 
        'ctools-modal-mymodule-style',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

More information about available keys, refer to [`theme_links()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_links/7) function in Drupal API.